# Which Chef software do we need to install for Windows?

Tags: chef, windows

I am using Windows 8.1.  Which Chef do I need to install to cover all Chef modes like workstation, node, and chef-server?

I want all three of these in my Windows 8.1.

Comment: https://docs.chef.io/platforms.html

Answer (score 4):

A node in chef terminology is a machine managed with chef-client.

Chef-client is available for various OS, windows, Linux, Aix, Mac etc.

However the chef-server is only available for linux.

Answer (score 3):

To clear which module you need to install & where, just go through the terminology of chef at [chef.io](https://docs.chef.io/chef_overview.html)
For workstation, you need to install [chefDK](https://downloads.chef.io/chefdk)

For node, you need to install [chefclient](https://downloads.chef.io/chef)

For chef server, you need to install [chefserver](https://downloads.chef.io/chef-server) - not available for windows

Note: Always use the stable and latest version of the above-mentioned components.Hope this helps.